# SQL table design help

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, many-to-many

I've taken over an application that has a SQL backend.  There are multiple tables, but the two that I'm concerned about are these:

```
QAProfile
---------
ProfileID <pk> -int
ProfileName
SecurityGroups -varchar(max)


SecurityGroups
--------------
GroupID <pk> -int
GroupName
```

My issue is that the the SecurityGroups field is a comma delimited list of GroupID values.

So the Profile table looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------------- 
| ProfileID | ProfileName | SecurityGroups | 
-------------------------------------------- 
|    1      |     foo     |  ,1,13,34,56,  | 
-------------------------------------------- 
|    2      |     bar     |  ,4,13,29,56,  | 
--------------------------------------------
```

A profile can have muliple security groups and a security group can be on muliple profiles

Any suggestions on how to re-engineer this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's good that you're looking to re-engineer this, since in general comma-delimited lists don't belong to SQL databases.

It looks like a simple [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) can replace the `SecurityGroups` column of the `QAProfile` table:

```
CREATE TABLE SecurityGroups_Profiles (
    GroupID     int    NOT NULL,
    ProfileID   int    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (GroupID, ProfileID),
    FOREIGN KEY (GroupID) REFERENCES SecurityGroups (GroupID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ProfileID) REFERENCES QAProfile (ProfileID)
);
```

Comment: yours is nicer, you even added the FK's! I figured they could do that themselves.

Comment: I don't agree with the statement: "comma delimited lists don't belong to SQL database" seems a bit dogmatic - there certainly are circumstances where such a strategy is greatly beneficial for performance reasons.

Comment: @James: You have a point. Added "in general" to that sentence to be more accurate.

Comment: In this case the `SecurityGroups` column violates first normal form (a non-scalar data type faked using `VARCHAR(MAX)`) and there is no way of enforcing declarative referential integrity between the domain values (which are of type `INTEGER`).

Answer (score 4):

If it was me, I would do it like this:

```
QAProfile
---------
ProfileID <pk> -int
ProfileName

SecurityGroups
--------------
GroupID <pk> -int
GroupName

QASecurityGroups
----------------
ProfileID<pk>
GroupID <pk>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Create Table QAProfileSecurityGroup (
 ProfileID int,
 GroupID int,
 PRIMARY KEY ( ProfileID, GroupID)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

- add table `ProfileSecurityGroups`
- parse that string for each profile and add pairs to the table
- change the app layer to use new structure
- drop the SecurityGroups column from the Profile table

[image]

Comment: Way over the top gotta give you +1 for whipping up a diagram!

Answer (score 1):

Yes piece of cake you could just create a junction table like this:

```
ProfileSecurityGroups
---------------------
Id, <pk> -int
ProfileId <fk>,
SecurityGroupId <fk>
```

Answer (score 1):

- A new Table ProfileToGroup should be added:

  ProfileID 
  GroupID
- You will need to write a SQL script to parse out the list of groups and insert records into the new table for each Profile/Group combination.
- Finally, the SecurityGroups column in the QAProfile table should be removed